# Сериализация многомерного массива

Tags: php, сериализация

Когда делаю сериализацию массива, состоящего из 3-4 многомерных массивов, все происходит норм, когда делаю сериализацию из массива, в котором больше 6 многомерных массивов, вроде бы все происходит норм, но десериализовать я их не могу.
Привожу пример того массива, который не хочет десериализовываться:

```
a:10:{
    i:0;a:4:{
        i:0;s:79:"Суп  овощной с фрикадельками из мяса курицы";i:1;s:1:"8";i:2;i:400;i:3;s:2:"50";
    }
    i:1;a:4:{
        i:0;s:91:"Мясо 'Атаман' (свинина, помидор, лук, сыр, чесн, м-з)";i:1;s:2:"11";i:2;i:902;i:3;s:2:"82";
    }
    i:2;a:4:{
        i:0;s:10:"Самсы";i:1;s:1:"5";i:2;i:175;i:3;s:2:"35";
    }
    i:3;a:4:{
        i:0;s:14:"Булочка";i:1;s:1:"5";i:2;i:100;i:3;s:2:"20";
    }
    i:4;a:4:{
        i:0;s:27:"Кисель ягодный";i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;i:35;i:3;s:2:"35";
    }
    i:5;a:4:{
        i:0;s:22:"С-т 'Малибу'";i:1;s:1:"7";i:2;i:294;i:3;s:2:"42";
    }
    i:6;a:4:{
        i:0;s:74:"Творожная запеканка со сгущёным молоком";i:1;s:1:"5";i:2;i:210;i:3;s:2:"42";
    }
    i:7;a:4:{
        i:0;s:59:"Бульон с куриным мясом и зеленью";i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;i:70;i:3;s:2:"70";
    }
    i:8;a:4:{
        i:0;s:13:"с рисом";i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;i:20;i:3;s:2:"20";
    }
    i:9;a:4:{
        i:0;s:28:"Сосиска в тесте";i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;i:40;i:3;s:2:"40";
    }
}
```

Comment: да не может такого быть.

Киньте код куда нибудь вашего скрипта!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно это из-за одинарных кавычек в словах. 
Пробуйте сериализовать `htmlspecialchars(serialize($array),ENT_QOUTES)` 
А при ансериализации `unserialize(htmlspecialchars_decode($serialize_array))`

Comment: Вы давно в `htmlspecialchars` последний раз массив толкали?

Comment: @Sh4dow опередил меня :)

Comment: Согласен, поменял ответ

Comment: Заодно можно еще в base64 закодировать, а потом раскодировать. На всякий случай.

Comment: Спасибо помогло!